# Javascript, Date.parse with no timezone

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I am having a problem with Javascript dates.

I receive an JSON that contains a date, when I try to get the date object it returns the value in a different timezone and usually move the date to a day before at 20hrs.

Example:

The value in json is: `"2014-06-01T00:00:00"`

When I do

```
var d2 = new Date(Date.parse("2014-06-01T00:00:00"))
```

it returns

> Sat May 31 2014 **20:00:00** GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

When I expected

> Sun Jun 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400

how can I fix this issue?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the "{}" toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.parse` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch in UTC, so no matter what date/time string you pass in, you'll get UTC out.  (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse for more information.)

If you want to convert that to local time, you'll have to know your offset from UTC.  You can get that from JavaScript thusly:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
```

(`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset` returns the offset in minutes, so we have to convert to milliseconds.)

Then you can construct your date with that offset:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse("2014-06-01T00:00:00") + offset);
```

If you want to interpret that date as if it were in a different timezone, you would just use whatever millisecond offset is appropriate for that timezone.  Keep in mind daylight savings, though: that will definitely complicate matters.

Comment: Using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` produces inconsistent results and doesn't always work, because of Daylight Savings.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin, I did mention that timezones complicate matters.  The OP mentioned nothing about the runtime JS environment, or whether or not this needs to be completely accurate or "mostly right most of the time".  Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: We ended up using a library (`date.js`) which I understand is not an ideal solution, but the fact that 40-50% of the time (during winter months) your solution is off by an hour.... isn't great.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin yeah, we used date.js too.  FYI, date.js is no longer supported; I recommend moving to day.js (https://day.js.org/), which has a nearly identical API but is actively maintained.

Comment: Also, @EliezerBerlin, I don't think my solution (presented here) is off by an hour during the winter months necessarily.  That would only be the case if the browser implementation of `getTimezoneOffset` is crap, and most browsers seem to get it right.  So I think this is an edge case for old browsers

Answer (score 1):

From the Mozilla documentation of [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> **ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support**
>
> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and time) can be passed and parsed. The UTC time-zone is used to interpret arguments in ISO 8601 format that do not contain time zone information.

Your value doesn't include time zone information, so it's assumed to be in UTC. Midnight UTC on the day in question is 8pm in your local time zone. Note that a `Date` object doesn't have the concept of a time zone in itself - it's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. When you convert it to a string with [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString), *that* uses the local time zone of the browser. You can use [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) to convert to a text representation using UTC instead (so in this case, you'd end up with the UTC midnight you started from).

Now in terms of what you can do to "fix" the issue... you need to start off by understanding what value you're trying to represent, and what you want to do with it. We can't really help you with that without more information.

Comment: I guess the easiest fix would be to append time zone manually to input string.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: To have a *fix*, we'd have to know what the OP is really trying to achieve - which isn't clear at the moment.